Arrays and File Help in C++
I am currently studying for my final exam, and I have a practice problem that is stumping me. I am trying to read from a file, but when I read into my array for the second time, it is not correctly reading it in.
This is my source code. It includes a comment block at the top for the practice problem.
/* Write a program to process a file called “grades.txt”. The file has the following format: a
person’s name on one line followed by 5 integer values, each on their own line. For example:
Billy Bob
100
90
58
93
87
Johnny Doe
0
100
100
98
7

Example Output:
Billy Bob 85.60
Johnny Doe 74.80
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

int main(){

    std::ifstream infile;

    infile.open("grades.txt");

    if (!infile){
        std::cout << "ERROR\n";
        std::exit(1);
    } 

    int grades[5]{};
    std::string name{};

    std::getline(infile, name);

    while (infile){
        for (int x{0}; x < 5; x++){
            infile >> grades[x];
        }

        int sum {};
        for (int x{0}; x < 5; x++){
            sum += grades[x];
        }

        double average {};
        average = sum / 5.0;

        std::cout << name << std::setw(20);
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << average << std::setw(8) << std::right << '\n';

        std::getline(infile, name);
    }

    infile.close();

    return 0;
}

I included a loop to print out my array, and this is the results i got.
Billy Bob               85.60
GRADES: 100
GRADES: 90
GRADES: 58
GRADES: 93
GRADES: 87
65.60
GRADES: 0
GRADES: 90
GRADES: 58
GRADES: 93
GRADES: 87
It is printing out the first set perfectly, but the second go around is when it doesn't grab the name, and the numbers do not match up. The file I am trying to process is in the comment block at the top of the code! Please help!
